# Where should "in one country" be?

Tags: adverb-placement

The two quoted ones are my rewrites. The bold one is the original. Where should I put "in one country"? What should it modify? I'm worried that, in my first version, "in one country" modifies the country instead of the households.

> The first graph displays the percentages of households **in one country**
> that owned electrical appliances between 1920 and 2019.

> The first graph displays the percentages of households that owned
> electrical appliances **in one country** between 1920 and 2019.

**The charts below show the changes in ownership of electrical appliances and amount of time spent doing housework in households in one country between 1920 and 2019.**

[image]

Comment: I think that _in one country_ must follow _households_.  Though it's an unlikely interpretation, your second version _could_ mean that households elsewhere own appliances which are all kept in this one country.

Comment: I think ***in one country*** would be better left out. The charts themselves contain no reference to a country anyway. I realize it's likely those charts are part of a larger "by country" ***set***, but it's not obvious to me there's any reason to indicate that in OP's text. But if it ***was*** important for some reason, I think it would be better to say *in **a** country* (making it slightly less likely that readers will be tearing their hair out wondering ***Which** country?*).

Comment: I was wondering if the asker used 'one country' as a place holder for a particular country. Otherwise it's a rather odd sentence.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I used "in one country" because the original (the bold sentence) uses it.